# Elasticsearch get the last ten added events

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with multiple types, one of these being **event** and I would like to get the last 10 events sorted by their start date

```
{

"from":0, 
"size":10,
"query":{
    "range":{
        "start":{
            "from":"2014-02-25 00:00:01 UTC",
            "to":"2014-03-04 23:59:00 UTC"
        }
    }
},
"filter" :{
    "and": [
        {
            "type": {
                "value": "event"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"sort":[
    { "start":
        {"order":"asc"}
    }
]
}
```

I have tried variations of the above query but cannot seem to get it working, elastic-search does not apply the type filter

Comment: the filter syntax above is correct (the and is not needed). have you tried to experiment with ``match_all`` just to pinpoint the problems with ``type``? if you are just interested in events you might as well just query their endpoint (like ``localhost:9200/idx/event/_search``)

Comment: please put this as your answer, I am such a dufus and you were absolutely on the money thank you

Comment: still the mystery remains, why you got different types

Comment: The `filter` is specified on the top-level, meaning it only applies to `hits` and not e.g. facets or aggregations. It's renamed to `post_filter` in 1.0. You probably want to use a `filtered`-query in this case.

Comment: Can you provide data that you've indexed? Would make easier to provide an answer.

Comment: Also the ES version.  I tested against 0.9.11.

Comment: I used elastic head to test the query with the added endpoint information it worked, multiple types due to the way we have mapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the filter syntax above is correct (the and is not needed).

if you are just interested in events you might as well just query their endpoint (like `localhost:9200/idx/event/_search`)

Answer (score 1):

In fact if you want to use the 'type' in your query, you have to do use the '_type' name with the underscore. This here is an example:

```
POST /items/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "_type": "item"
        }
    }
}
```